# parsing in PHP variable to XSLT setParameter

Tags: php, variables

I would like to set some variables in my PHP document that get parsed through into the XSLT I am generating.

I can set a parameter like this:

```
$xp->setParameter($namespace, 'title', 'My title');
```

and echo it in my XSLT like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$title"/>
```

However, I would like to set the value of 'title' dynamically.

I thought I should be able to set:

```
$title = 'My title';
```

and then

```
$xp->setParameter($namespace, 'title', '$title');
```

however, when I do this my XSLT just outputs

```
$title
```

as raw text, rather than 'My title' as I would have expected. Please could you let me know how I can set this value correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use variables, you should use variables

```
$xp->setParameter($namespace, 'title', $title);
```